# How do I set CLASSPATH variable for Tomcat in 12.10?

Tags: bash, java, environment-variables, openjdk

Previously, I have set the `JAVA_HOME` path using the terminal with the following command:

`export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386" >> ~/.bashrc`

Now, I want to set the `CLASSPATH` environment variable to include the `servlet-api.jar`. Basically, what I am trying to achieve is that I should not need to type the classpath to `servlet-api.jar`  every time I compile a Java program nor should I have to type `-cp .` when compiling a regular Java program whose `.class` file is in the same directory

I am a newbie from Windows so please a step-by-step guide would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CLASSPATH` variable can be extended in this way

```
CLASSPATH=${CLASSPATH}:/path_to_classes_dir
```

or

```
CLASSPATH=${CLASSPATH}:/path_to.jar
```

**But I think your question is not reflecting your right intention.**

`servlet-api.jar` is an api. It is only needed at *compile time*.
On *run time* an implementation is provided by a container like *tomcat*.